# By giving coins to other civilization, would it improve relationships?

Tags: civilization

I have eliminated 6 empires and I am the most advance empire in the game and I am also the most powerful in the game. Everyones' status is HOSTILE. I'd like to improve everyone status. I usually give 500 coins (Since I'm also the most wealthiest) to bankrupt civilisations. Would this improve relationships? If not, how can I improve?

Comment: The later in the game and the more powerful you are the harder does it get to maintain peace.

Comment: Which Civilization do you mean? The original?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it gives you a little +rep. But you need more than that. Spies, traderoutes, resources, same religion, same Government, not to big armies at their borders also helps. But you have to give them time to forget all the mean things you have done also.